# How to get Kinect v2 frame by cv2.videocapture()?

Tags: opencv, kinect, yolov5

I'd like to use Kinect v2 as a webcam to run YOLO, through yolo source code I found that the stream is captured by `cv2.videocapture()` I searched the opencv documentation and I got the API of Kinect `cv2.videocapture(cv2.CAP_OPENNI2)` but I can't get any stream from this function. However, I can get color and depth frame by `dev.create_color_stream()`, but it's not easy to process it to fit YOLO. Appreciate!

**Environment:**

Ubuntu:20.04

Openni:2.3.0

Opencv-python:4.5.5.64

Libfreenect

```py
from openni import openni2
import numpy as np
import cv2

openni2.initialize()     # can also accept the path of the OpenNI redistribution

dev = openni2.Device.open_any()
print(dev.get_device_info())

#
# depth_stream = dev.create_depth_stream()
# color_stream = dev.create_color_stream()
# depth_stream.start()
# color_stream.start()


# get depth img,default size: 424x512
def get_last_depth():
    #depth_stream = dev.create_depth_stream()
    #depth_stream.start()
    # show depth img
    frame = depth_stream.read_frame()
    dframe_data = np.array(frame.get_buffer_as_triplet()).reshape([480, 640, 2])
    dpt1 = np.asarray(dframe_data[:, :, 0], dtype='float32')
    dpt2 = np.asarray(dframe_data[:, :, 1], dtype='float32')
    dpt2 *= 255
    dpt = dpt1 + dpt2
    #cv2.imshow('dpt', dpt)
    return dpt
    depth_stream.stop()

#get rgb img, 1080x1920x4
def get_last_rgb():
    #color_stream = dev.create_color_stream()
    #color_stream.start()
    # show
    cframe = color_stream.read_frame()
    cframe_data = np.array(cframe.get_buffer_as_triplet()).reshape([1080, 1920, 3])
    R = cframe_data[:, :, 0]
    G = cframe_data[:, :, 1]
    B = cframe_data[:, :, 2]
    cframe_data = np.transpose(np.array([B, G, R]), [1, 2, 0])
    # print(cframe_data.shape)
    #cv2.imshow('color', cframe_data)
    #print(cframe_data)
    return cframe_data
    color_stream.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    for i in range(1000):
        capture = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_OPENNI2)
        capture.grab()


        ret_d,depth_map = capture.retrieve(cv2.CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_MAP)
        ret_f, frame = capture.retrieve(cv2.CAP_OPENNI_IMAGE_GENERATOR)

        # print(cv2.CAP_OPENNI_BGR_IMAGE, cv2.CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_MAP)
        cv2.imshow('kinect',frame)
        [enter image description here][1]print(ret_f,frame)
        # rgb = get_last_rgb()
        # cv2.imshow('rgb',rgb)
        # depth = get_last_depth()
        # print("depth:",depth[100][100])
        # cv2.imshow('depth',depth)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        # print(i)
    # close the divice
    dev.close()
```

Comment: Is your opencv compiled with openni? Try cv2.getBuildInformation

Comment: No openni shown under videoIO, so I guess that could be the problem, thank you! I'm going to fix it! Appreciate it a lot!